# Theorem $8.38$ - Elliptic Partial Differential Equations by Gilbarg and Trudinger

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation, elliptic-equations

I am trying understand why if $u$ is an eigenfunction for the first eigenvalue $\sigma_1$, then $|u|$ is one also.

> **Theorem 8.38.** Let $L$ be a self-adjoint operator satisfying $(8.5)$ and $(8.6)$. Then the minimum eigenvalue is simple and has a positive eigenfunction.

> *Proof.* If $u$ is an eigenfunction of $\sigma_1$, then it follows from the formula $(8.92)$ that $|u|$ is one also.

Relevant informations:

$(8.92)$ is the variational characterization of $\sigma_1$. More precisely, if the operator $L$ has the form

> $$Lu = D_i(a^{ij}D_j u + b^i u) - b^i D_i u + c u,$$
> where $[a^{ij}]$ is symmetric,
> then
> The associated quadratic form on $H = W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ is then given by
> $$\mathscr{L}(u,u) = \int_{\Omega} (a^{ij} D_i u D_j u + 2 b^i u D_i u + c u^2) dx.$$
> The ratio
> $$J(u) = \frac{\mathscr{L}(u,u)}{(u,u)}, u \not\equiv 0, u \in H$$
> is called the Rayleigh quotient.
> $$(8.92) \ \sigma = \inf_H J.$$

The conditions satisfied by $L$ are
$$ \quad a^{i j}(x) \xi_{i} \xi_{j} \geqslant \lambda|\xi|^{2}, \quad \forall x \in \Omega, \xi \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \tag{8.5}$$
We also assume (unless stated otherwise) that $L$ has bounded coefficients; that is for some constants $\Lambda$ and $v \geqslant 0$ we have for all $x \in \Omega$

$$
\sum\left|a^{i j}(x)\right|^{2} \leqslant \Lambda^{2}, \quad \lambda^{-2} \sum\left(\left|b^{i}(x)\right|^{2}+\left|c^{i}(x)\right|^{2}\right)+\lambda^{-1}|d(x)| \leqslant v^{2}
\tag{8.6}$$
[Transcribed from this screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZuYZ.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you should include (8.92) in the post. Also typing IMO is preferrable to pictures

Comment: I wonder if there are typos in $L$ or $\mathscr{L}$, I integrate by part but find something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let’s try to evaluate $\mathscr{L}(|u|,|u|)$ keeping in mind that $|u| = u^+ + u^-$ where:

- $u^+ (x) = \max \{ u(x), 0\}$ and $u^- (x) := \max \{-u(x), 0\}$ for $x \in \Omega$,
- $u^\pm \geq 0$ a.e. in $\Omega^\pm := \{ x \in \Omega : \pm u(x) \geq 0\}$,
- $u^\mp = 0$ in $\Omega^\pm$,
- and $u = u^+ - u^-$;

we get:

\begin{split} \mathscr{L}(|u|,|u|) &= \mathscr{L}(u^+ + u^-, u^+ + u^-) \\
&= \int_{\Omega^+} (a^{ij} D_i u^+ D_j u^+ + 2 b^i u^+ D_i u^+ + c (u^+)^2) dx + \int_{\Omega^-} (a^{ij} D_i u^- D_j u^- + 2 b^i u^- D_i u^- + c (u^-)^2) dx \\
&= \int_{\Omega^+} (a^{ij} D_i u^+ D_j u^+ + 2 b^i u^+ D_i u^+ + c (u^+)^2) dx + \int_{\Omega^-} (a^{ij} D_i (-u^-) D_j (-u^-) + 2 b^i (-u^-)D_i (-u^-) + c (-u^-)^2) dx \\
&= \mathscr{L}(u^+ - u^-, u^+ - u^-) \\
&= \mathscr{L} (u,u)\;. \end{split}

Since $\| |u|\|_2^2 = ( |u|, |u|) = (u,u) = \|u\|^2$, we have equality between the Rayleigh quotients $\frac{\mathscr{L} (|u|, |u|)}{\| |u|\|^2}$ and $\frac{\mathscr{L} (u,u)}{\|u\|^2}$, therefore if $u$ is a first eigenfunction then $|u|$ also does.